# How to make Sentry Ignore some Exceptions?

Tags: c#, serilog, sentry

I'm using serilog to log exceptions to Sentry. I want to ignore some exceptions and not log them to Sentry. I would like to read those exceptions from the app settings file if possible. I tried this, but it did not work. I'm trying here to ignore the NotImplementedException exception.

Appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logfile": {
    "Name": "/logs/log-Service-.txt"
  },
  "Sentry": {
    "Dsn": "https://sentry.dns"
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "IgnoreList": {
      "ExceptionTypes": [
        "NotImplementedException"
      ]
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "myconnection"
  }
}
```

HostBuilderExtensions.cs

```
    public static class HostBuilderExtensions
    {
        public static IHostBuilder UseCustomSerilog(this IHostBuilder builder, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var ignoreList = configuration.GetSection("Serilog:IgnoreList:ExceptionTypes")
            .Get<string[]>() ?? Array.Empty<string>();

            return builder.UseSerilog((context, config) =>
            {
                config.MinimumLevel.Verbose()
                    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Fatal)
                    .WriteTo.Udp(
                        remoteAddress: configuration.GetSection("Logstash")["Host"] ?? throw new InvalidOperationException(),
                        remotePort: int.Parse(configuration.GetSection("Logstash")["Port"] ?? throw new InvalidOperationException()),
                        family: AddressFamily.InterNetwork, formatter: new CompactJsonFormatter()
                    )
                    .Enrich.WithProperty("type", configuration.GetSection("Logstash")["Type"] ?? throw new InvalidOperationException())
                    .WriteTo.File(
                        new CompactJsonFormatter(),
                        configuration.GetSection("Logfile")["Name"] ?? throw new InvalidOperationException(),
                        rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day
                    )
                    .WriteTo.Console()
                    .WriteTo.Sentry(o =>
                    {
                        o.Dsn = configuration.GetSection("Sentry")["Dns"];
                        o.MinimumEventLevel = LogEventLevel.Error;
                        o.MinimumBreadcrumbLevel = LogEventLevel.Error;
                        o.SetBeforeSend((sentryEvent, _) =>
                        {
(exceptionsToIgnore.Contains(sentryEvent.Exception?.GetType().FullName))
                            if (ignoreList.Contains(sentryEvent.Exception?.GetType().FullName))
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Ignored");
                                return null;
                            }

                            return sentryEvent;
                        });
                        //o.AddExceptionFilterForType<NotImplementedException>();
                    })
                    .Enrich.FromLogContext();
            });
        }
    }
```

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.WebHost.UseSentry();

builder.Host.UseCustomSerilog(builder.Configuration);

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSwagger();

app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    string swaggerJsonBasePath = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.RoutePrefix) ? "." : "..";
    c.SwaggerEndpoint($"{swaggerJsonBasePath}/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Bet");
});

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseMiddleware<GlobalExceptionHandling>();

app.UseMiddleware<GlobalLoggerHandling>();

app.UseMiddleware<ValidationMiddleware>();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

It still logs  the exception.

Thanks

Comment: You have debugged the SetBeforeSend callback and seen that the if statement did what you expect?

Comment: I cannot debug it. @Ralf

Comment: Then get you into the state of debugging. You will have a hard time solving anything in programming by guessing. Hint for the FullName Property you use from the docs "The fully qualified name of the type, including its namespace".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Sentry codebase has an [example of how ignore exceptions of a particular type](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/blob/main/src/Sentry/Internal/ExceptionTypeFilter.cs)

```cs
class ExceptionTypeFilter<TException> : IExceptionFilter where TException : Exception
{
    private readonly Type _filteredType = typeof(TException);
    public bool Filter(Exception ex) => _filteredType.IsInstanceOfType(ex);
}
```

You could wire that up when configuring Sentry with something like:

```cs
SentrySdk.Init(options => {
    // All your other config here...
    options.AddExceptionFilter(new ExceptionTypeFilter<NotImplementedException>());
});
```

You can obviously modify that to do fancier stuff and the `SetBeforeSend` callback event that you've found is a good pick to filter events more generally (not just events for exceptions).

In situations where you can't run the code in a debugger (which hopefully are rare), Logging might help. You could/should also try to test your code with unit tests before deploying it. Ideally though, you're going to want to be able to run stuff in a debugger to make sense of things.

Comment: That did not work either. I solved it with function
        private void AddExceptionToSentry(Exception ex)
        {
            if (exceptionIgnoreList is not null && !exceptionIgnoreList.Contains(ex.GetType().Name))
            {            
                var sentryClient = new RavenClient(_dns);
                sentryClient.Capture(new SentryEvent(ex));                
            }
        }

Comment: The Raven client is extremely old and no longer maintained.  James's answer is correct with regard to the current [Sentry .NET SDK](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dotnet/).